# Is an AsyncApexJob record inserted immediately at the end of a transaction?

Tags: apex, future, asyncapexjob, transaction, concurrency

Is an `AsyncApexJob` record inserted immediately at the end of a transaction or is it possible that there is a delay between those two events? I couldn't find firm guarantee in the documentation on that.

As a specific example, I'm calling an `@future` annotated method in the transaction T<sub>1</sub> and I'd like to monitor its progress. It returns `void`, but I can query the `AsyncApexJob` table to try to locate it (provided that there are no similar calls at the same time). Since the `@future` job is only queued **after** a successful transaction, I can only reach it after the transaction T<sub>1</sub> ended, so I'd start another transaction T<sub>2</sub> immediately after to monitor it.

The question is whether **after** means *immediately at the end*, or there can be some delay *d* before the record can be found in the `AsyncApexJob` table?

Illustrated, if there's no delay, then T<sub>2</sub> is guaranteed to see the `AsyncApexJob` record as long as it starts after T<sub>1</sub>

```
T1 o------>
          * (AsyncApexJob record inserted by system)
T2         o---->
```

If there is some delay *d*, then T<sub>2</sub> is not guaranteed to see the record if it starts after T<sub>2</sub>, but before *d* has passed.

```
T1 o----->
         [--d--]* (AsyncApexJob record inserted by system)
T2        o---->
```

Comment: What about using Queueable Apex? Async Job chaining plus monitoring, both possible with.

Comment: @MarcinSz. The job I'm to monitor is not under my control. Otherwise a great idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this, and it's available *immediately* in the same transaction, before the current transaction completes. Obviously, this Id won't be available to other transactions before "final commit," but by the time T2 runs, it is guaranteed to have access to that record.

```
futureimm.exec();
asyncapexjob j = [select id from asyncapexjob order by createddate desc limit 1];
```

To avoid false positives, I'd consider restricting the query to just the name or Id of the apex class that gets called, and do so as soon as possible after calling the method to reduce the possibility that another transaction will just happen to complete the same millisecond that you call the query.